# Installing packages with dependencies using puppet

Tags: puppet

I am new to `puppet`, for the process of learning it I created `Puppet Master` and `Puppet Slave` setup and configured a `mysql` module to install mysql on `Puppet client`. Below is the manifest file.

```
class mysql {
    package { ["mysql-server-5.5", "libaio1", "libdbd-mysql-perl", "libdbi-perl", "libhtml-template-perl", "libmysqlclient18", "mysql-client-5.5", "mysql-common", "mysql-server-core-5.5"]:
    ensure => present,
    allowcdrom => 'true',
    }
}
```

The `package` resource contains all the dependencies of mysql-server. But I am getting the below error.

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmysqlclient18 mysql-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 738 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3513 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  mysql-common libmysqlclient18
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
Error: /Stage[main]/Mysql/Package[libmysqlclient18]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install libmysqlclient18' returned 100: Reading package lists...
```

I also tried adding `install_options: "--force-yes"` as mentioned in the error output, but still getting in to the same issue.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Crossposting is discouraged. http://serverfault.com/questions/667804/installing-packages-with-dependencies-using-puppet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below manifest. The issue is that you have to add `-f` and `--allow-unauthenticated` options for `apt-get` to resolve the dependencies automatically and install them. Once these flags are added it is not necessary to add each and every dependent package to the `package` resource.

```
class mysql {
    package { ["mysql-server-5.5"]:
    ensure => present,
    allowcdrom => 'true',
    install_options => ['--allow-unauthenticated', '-f'],
    }
}
```